# c++ member function hides global function

Tags: c++, function, hide, global, member

This code snippet doesn't compile:

```
struct M {
    int i;
    int j;
};

void f(M& m) {
    m.i++;
}

struct N {
    M m;
    void f(int i) {
        f(m); // compilation error
    }
};
```

clang says : `No viable conversion from 'M' to 'int'`
Seems my member function hides global function.

I changed the error line into `::f(m)` to help name resolution, but still fails. Does it mean that in c++ member function, cannot call global overload function with same name but different parameter list?

How to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `::f(m);` because writing `f(m)` inside the member function is equivalent to `this->f(m)`. That is, for `this->f(m)`, the global `f(M&)` is not even considered and only the member function is considered.

Comment: _"I changed the error line into ::f(m) to help name resolution, but still fails"_ - please post the error message, and compiler details. Changing to `::f(m);` works well on MSVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> c++ member function **hides** global function

The **problem** is that for the call expression `f(m)` *name lookup* finds the member function `N::f(int)` and so the search/lookup stops. Now this found member function `N::f(int)` has a parameter of type `int` but we're passing an argument of type `M` and since there is no implicit conversion from `M` to `int`, this call fails.

To **solve** this, use the scope `operator::` to tell the compiler that you want to call the global function `f` as shown below:

```
struct N {
    M m;
    void f(int i) {
//------vv---------->use the scope operator :: to call the global version
        ::f(m); 
    }
};
```

[Working Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pxh6re9ee)

Comment: OP specifically mentioned that they tried `::f(m);` and still got errors. In a comment above I was trying to get more info.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes, that is why i added a [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pxh6re9ee) that shows that it works with msvc as opposed to OP's claim. Moreover, OP seems to be not understanding the reason for why the call `f(m)` does not work. So, I've explained it in my answer.

Comment: Um, this is **exactly** what the informal term "hiding" usually means: the name in the inner scope hides the name in the outer scope. If `N::f` was named `N::g` instead the call would work.

Comment: @PeteBecker What i mean is that `this->f(m)` is a qualified call and so the global function `f(M&)` is not even considered. **There is no "hiding" here. We're telling exactly where the function is to be found**.

Comment: The code doesn't say `this->f(m)`. It just calls `f(m)`. Again, it would work if `N::f` had been named `N::g`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Note that i've said 2 times in my answer that writing `f(m)` is equivalent to writing `this->f(m)`.

Comment: You've said it, but it's not true. If `N::f` had been named `N::g`, `this->f(m)` would fail, but `f(m)` would work. Try it.

Comment: @PeteBecker Here is a link to confirm that `f(m)` is equivalent to `this->f(m)`. [Demo](https://cppinsights.io/s/e730ed4d). Note in the above mentioned demo, the call `f(5)` is changed to `this->f(5)` in the right pane. Same applies to `f(m)`.

Comment: Again: change the name of `N::f` to `N::g` and look at what happens when `N::g` calls `this->f(m)` (which doesn't exist) and when `N::g` calls `f(m)` (which works). They are not equivalent, regardless of how many times you say it or what some IDE tells you.

Comment: @PeteBecker I see, so i am changing the wording in my answer to: *"the problem is that for the call expression `f(m)`, name lookup finds the member function `N::f(int)` and so the search stops. Now, this found member function takes an argument of type `int` but you're passing an `M` and hence the error"*.

Comment: @JasonLiam -- exactly right!